# Running `exec` with a Bash built-in

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I defined a shell function (let's call it `clock`), which I want to use as a wrapper to another command, similar to the `time` function, e.g. `clock ls -R`.

My shell function performs some tasks and then ends with `exec "$@"`.

I'd like this function to work even with shell built-ins, e. g. `clock time ls -R` should output the result of the `time` built-in, and not the `/usr/bin/time` executable. But `exec` always ends up running the command instead.

How can I make my Bash function work as a wrapper that also accepts shell built-ins as arguments?

**Edit**: I just learned that `time` is not a Bash built-in, but a [special reserved word](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#index-time) related to pipelines. I'm still interested in a solution for built-ins even if it does not work with `time`, but a more general solution would be even better.

Comment: You need to invoke a shell explicitly, using `exec bash -c \' "$@" \'`. Unless your command in the first parameter is a recognised as a shell script, then it will be interpreted as a binary to be run directly. Alternatively, and more simply, just miss out the `exec` and call `"@"` from your original shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You defined a bash function. So you are already in a bash shell when invoking that function. So that function could then simply look like:

```
clock(){
  echo "do something"
  $@
}
```

That function can be invoked with bash builtins, special reserved words, commands, other defined functions:

An alias:

```
$ clock type ls
do something
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

A bash builtin:

```
$ clock type type
do something
type is a shell builtin
```

Another function:

```
$ clock clock
do something
do something
```

An executable:

```
$ clock date
do something
Tue Apr 21 14:11:59 CEST 2015
```

Comment: In this case, is there any difference between running `$@` and `exec $@`, if I know I am running an actual command?

Comment: When you use `exec`, the command replaces the shell. Hence there are no builtins, aliases, special reserved words, defined words anymore, because the executable is executed via system call `execve()`. That syscall expects an executable file.

Comment: But from the point of view of an external observer, is it still possible to distinguish them, e.g. with `exec $0` there is a single process, while `$@` still has two.

Comment: Yes, `$@` has the running shell as parent and the command as child process. But when you want to use builtins, aliases and so on, you have to preserve the shell. Or start a new one.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to launch a shell builtin or shell keyword is to launch a new shell because exec “replaces the shell with the given command”. You should replace your last line with:

```
IFS=' '; exec bash -c "$*"
```

This works with both builtins and reserved words; the principle is the same.

Answer (score 3):

If the wrapper needs to insert code *before* the given command, an alias would work as they are expanded at a very early stage:

```
alias clock="do this; do that;"
```

Aliases are almost literally inserted in place of the aliased word, so the trailing `;` is important – it makes `clock time foo` expand to `do this; do that; time foo`.

You can abuse this to create [magic aliases](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/aliases.html) which even bypass quoting.

---

For inserting code *after* a command, you could use the "DEBUG" hook.

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap "<code>" DEBUG
```

Specifically:

```
shopt -s extdebug
trap 'if [[ $BASH_COMMAND == "clock "* ]]; then
          eval "${BASH_COMMAND#clock }"; echo "Whee!"; false
      fi' DEBUG
```

The hook still runs *before* the command, but as it returns `false` it tells bash to cancel the execution (because the hook already ran it via eval).

As another example, you can use this to alias `command please` to `sudo command`:

```
trap 'case $BASH_COMMAND in *\ please) eval sudo ${BASH_COMMAND% *}; false; esac' DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could come up with so far would be to perform a case analysis to distinguish whether the first argument is a command, built-in, or keyword, and fail in the last case:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $(type -t "$1") in
  file)
    # do stuff
    exec "$@"
    ;;
  builtin)
    # do stuff
    builtin "$@"
    ;;
  keyword)
    >&2 echo "error: cannot handle keywords: $1"
    exit 1
    ;;
  *)
    >&2 echo "error: unknown type: $1"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

It does not handle `time`, however, so there might be a better (and more concise) solution.