# Wrapping `time` (and similar keywords) in call from another script

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, script

I have a Bash script (let's call it `clock`) which should work as a wrapper similar to the `time` keyword in Bash, e.g. `clock ls` should do something and then run `ls`. Here is an example of this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "do something"
$@
```

Note that it does not use `exec`, to allow wrapping built-ins.

However, when the argument to wrap is the `time` keyword, it does not work as expected: the output shows it runs the `/usr/bin/time` command, not the shell keyword.

How can I make my wrapper script treat keywords (such as `time`) exactly as if they had been typed directly in the shell?

**Note**: In my [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/904173), I learned how to make it work when `clock` was a Bash function in the same script, but in my real use case, `clock` is actually a Bash script itself, so the previous solution does not work. Also, the solutions mentioned in the related question (using `$@` directly, or running `exec bash -c ""$@""`) do not work in this case.

One partial solution I found was to use `eval $@`, but it is very unreliable. It works in this simple case with `time`, but fails in many situations, such as in `clock ls '~$Document1'`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Analysis

The problem is `time` you want to use is designed to handle entire pipelines in Bash. It wouldn't be possible if `time` was recognized and "executed" like any regular command (e.g. the external `time` executable) or even a builtin. It has to be a keyword. The shell needs to recognize it very early, about the time it recognizes pipelines.

You cannot inject working `|`, `&&`, or `;` into the shell code by making them pop out from a variable (or parameter) during variable expansion. At the time variable expansion occurs the shell already knows what the logic of the line is. Similarly it's too late for `time` to pop out and be interpreted as the keyword.

This means the only way to pass `time` via a variable (or parameter) and have it interpreted as the keyword is to evaluate it (along with the entire command-to-be) *from the beginning* after variable expansion. This is what `eval` or `bash -c` can do. You cannot avoid it.

---

#### Basic solution

The simplest method would be to require `clock` (your script) to accept only one argument. You would use it like this:

```
clock ls
clock 'ls -l'
clock 'time ls -l'
clock 'time ls -l | wc -l'
```

Inside the script the crucial command should be:

```
eval "$1"
# or
exec bash -c "$1" "$0"
```

(If you wonder about this `"$0"` then read [this](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690). The point is to make `$0` in the new shell the same as in the current shell. Its value will most likely be `clock`.)

I guess you would like to be able to conveniently run `clock time ls -l` instead of `clock 'time ls -l'`. If so, the crucial command(s) in the script should be:

```
eval "$@"
# or
IFS=$' \t\n'; eval "$*"
# or
IFS=$' \t\n'; exec bash -c "$*" "$0"
```

If I were you I would prefer `eval` because it doesn't start `bash` from the beginning (performance) and it keeps unexported variables available (these may be relevant if instead/aside of `echo "do something"` your script sets some variables).

I would prefer `eval "$@"` over `eval "$*"` because the former doesn't depend on `IFS`. Upon receiving multiple arguments (which may be the case with `"$@"`) [`eval`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#eval) concatenates them together, separating with spaces, before it evaluates the result. This is equivalent to passing `"$*"` (which is always a single argument), if only the `IFS` variable begins with space. Wherever I used `"$*"` I made sure `IFS` begins with space in case your script changed the variable earlier for whatever reason. Space+tab+newline is the default value.

My choice:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "do something"
eval "$@"
```

---

#### Quoting

Whatever you choose, double-quote `$@`, `$*` or `$1` in the script. Note there are three stages of expansion:

1. When you pass `clock whatever` to a shell, the shell parses the command like it always does: token recognition, brace expansion, tilde expansion [and so on](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions). You can avoid (in context of this list: possibly delay) various expansions by quoting and/or escaping.
2. When your script gets to `"$@"`, `"$*"` or `"$1"`, parameter expansion occurs. If the parameter wasn't double-quoted, the result would undergo word splitting and filename expansion. You most likely don't want these at this stage if you use `eval`; and you definitely don't want these if you use `bash -c`.
3. Finally, when `eval` or `bash -c` does its job, it parses the string passed as argument(s) from the beginning. Again you can avoid various expansions by proper quoting or escaping. Note quotes and/or backslashes that should suppress some expansion, or characters like `*` or snippets like `{a,b,c}` or `$foo` that should get expanded at this stage – they should be originally quoted or escaped so they survive the first stage rather than being "used up" too early.

You should carefully quote and/or escape at the first stage, being aware and planning how the command will look at the last stage.

If you choose the solution with `"$@"` (or `"$*"`) rather than with `"$1"`, the following two commands will be equivalent:

```
clock 'ls -l'
clock ls -l
```

(unless the custom part of your script distinguishes them). But not these two:

```
clock 'ls -l | wc -l'
clock ls -l | wc -l
```

Note this is very similar to how commands like `watch 'ls -l'` or `ssh user@host 'ls -l'` behave. You can omit quotes and get the same results. Still `watch 'ls -l | wc -l'` and `watch ls -l | wc -l` are not equivalent; neither are `ssh user@host 'ls -l > foo.txt'` and `ssh user@host ls -l > foo.txt`.

---

#### Your attempts

> using `$@` directly

Sole `$@` does not provide any additional evaluation after variable expansion. When `time` pops up it's too late to interpret it as the keyword.

If `time` was not the issue then `$@` or `exec`$@`might be a good idea, but think twice if you want`$@` unquoted in such case.

---

> running `exec bash -c ""$@""`

This is wrong and I notified the author of the answer you got it from (the answer was improved). These neighboring double-quotes cancel each other out. In effect `$@` is unquoted and prone to word splitting and filename generation, as mentioned above. But even `"$@"` would be wrong here because `bash -c` takes exactly one argument as code. Following arguments (if any) define positional parameters (from 0, [there's a reason for this](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)). If your script uses this flawed code then e.g. `clock ls -l` will run `ls`, not `ls -l`; Even `clock`ls -l`will run`ls` without the argument because of word splitting.

---

> One partial solution I found was to use `eval $@`, but it is very unreliable. It works in this simple case with `time`, but fails in many situations, such as in `clock ls '~$Document1'`.

By single-quoting you protected `$Document` from being expanded (as a variable) in the first stage, but not in the last stage. With slightly different string `~` could also be problematic. Unquoted `$@` introduced the possibility of problems in between, although not in this particular case. You need to protect `$` *twice*:

```
clock ls '~\$Document1'
```

My basic solution requires protecting `$` twice in this case as well. To make `time` work as you want you need this additional stage of expansion, so you just need to deal with this.

Compare `watch ls '~$Document1'` and `watch ls '~\$Document1'`. The same situation.

There is a trick. See below.

---

#### The trick

The ability to choose at which stage some substring gets expanded is useful in case of `watch` or `ssh`.

E.g. you may want to monitor sizes of already existing `*.tmp` files without paying attention to new files. In this case you need `*` to be expanded once: `watch ls -l *.tmp`. Or you may want to include new files matching the pattern. In this case you need `*` to be expanded repeatedly: `watch 'ls -l *.tmp'`. With `ssh` you may want a variable to be expanded locally or on the remote server. For both tools it's sometimes useful to delay expansion.

Your script, however, should work similarly to the `time` keyword. The keyword does not introduce additional stage of expansion and your example with `~$Document1` shows that you don't want to introduce it. Still, according to my analysis you need it, but only to interprets words like `time` (passed as arguments) as keywords.

There is a way to suppress these unwanted expansions at the last stage. You can use the `Q` operator earlier:

> `${parameter@operator}`
>
> The expansion is either a transformation of the value of `parameter` or information about `parameter` itself, depending on the value of `operator`. Each `operator` is a single letter:
>
> `Q`
>   The expansion is a string that is the value of `parameter` quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))</sup>

This adds one level of single-quoting/escaping to the expanded string. Now the idea is to use it at our stage 2, so at stage 3 these extra quotes will prevent various expansions (and get removed).

Simply changing `eval "$@"` to `eval "${@@Q}"` will result in:

- ability to run `clock ls '~$Document1'` just like that (nice!);
- inability to run `clock 'time ls -l | wc -l'` (oh well);
- inability to recognize `time` in `clock time ls -l` as a keyword (oops!); at stage 3 `time` would be single-quoted and `'time'` is not a keyword.

The solution is not to use `Q` for the first command line argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "do something"
cmnd="$1"
shift
eval "$cmnd" "${@@Q}"
```

The first command line argument to `clock` is not protected from expansion at stage 3, but other arguments are. In result:

- you can run `clock ls '~$Document1'` just like that (nice!);
- you can run `clock 'time ls -l | wc -l'` (good), although you need to mind the quotes for stage 1 *and* stage 3 ([this question](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690) may help in some cases);
- `time` in `clock time …` or `clock 'time …'` is the `time` you want (yay!).

Should you worry about the first command line argument to `clock` not being protected from expansion at stage 3? Not really. It will be either a full long command (like a pipeline) quoted as a whole, then you should treat it like a long command passed to `watch` or `ssh` as one argument; or it will be a keyword/builtin/command that cannot trigger any undesired expansion at stage 3 because command names are deliberately simple and safe (no `$`, `~` or such). It would be different if you wanted to run `clock '*' …` or `clock './~$Document1' …`. I believe you have no reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember, bash has the `builtin` command, which forces it to run, you guessed it, the builtin command, even if there's a file in `PATH` with the same name.

---

I tested, by making this script in `/usr/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is /usr/bin/cd, and it does nothing"
```

And here are the results:

```
jarmund@jarmint/etc$ /usr/bin/cd ~
This is /usr/bin/cd, and it does nothing
jarmund@jarmint/etc$ builtin cd ~
jarmund@jarmint~$
```

**Conclusion:** prefixing your command with `builtin` should remove any ambiguety the shell might be experiencing.

Comment: The problem is that `time` is not an actual built-in, but a [reserved keyword](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) (related to pipelines), therefore `builtin time` does not work (at least in my Bash), and there is no equivalent (as far as I know) to `command`/`builtin` for such keywords.