# How can I pass a block as an argument to a bash function?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'd like to create a bash function that can get a bash code block like `time` does:

```
time {
  echo 123
  echo "Something else"
  sleep 1
}
```

Basically I'd like to be able to wrap the block with my bash code.

**Edit**: Updated my question after the first answer of @DavidPostill♦ and the comments:
For example, I'd like to wrap a code block with 2>&1 > /dev/null and also the time it with `time`. Should I write a program outside bash to do that?

```
function myfunction() {
  time { $1 } 2>&1 /dev/null
}
myfunction { sleep 1 }
```

**Edit 2**: Upon further reading it seems like it isn't possible as `time` is a special case for bash.

Comment: Note: `time` can do this because its a *keyword* in Bash. It's recognized by the parser. If you use `/usr/bin/time` instead (or `command time` or some function or a builtin), then it will be a syntax error. What exactly do you want your function to do? Maybe we can do this using a different syntax.

Comment: Can't do this in bash. The closest you get is to define a function containing the code you want as a block, and then pass the function name to your function that wants a block.

Comment: I'd like to wrap a code block with 2>&1 > /dev/null and also time it with `time`. Should I write a program outside bash to do that?

Comment: Somewhat similar: [Wrapping `time` (and similar keywords) in call from another script](https://superuser.com/q/904339/432690).

Comment: So, it seems it isn't possible with the syntax I had in mind, right? what are my options, per the edit?

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass blocks around directly as if they were objects, but you can pass the file descriptor (FD) of a redirect block (`<()`) and time the output of that (or do whatever to it). The inner `{} 2>&1` is needed to capture the stderr on the same FD:

```
function myfunction() {
  time cat $1 >/dev/null
}
myfunction <({ 
  echo 123
  echo "Something else"
  sleep 1 
} 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I'd like to be able to wrap the function with my bash code and pass arguments

> **Functions with parameters sample**
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash 
> function quit {
>    exit
> }  
> function e {
>     echo $1 
> }  
> e Hello
> e World
> quit
> echo foo
> ```
>
> The function `e` prints the first argument it receives.
>
> Arguments, within functions, are treated in the same manner as
> arguments given to the script.

Source [BASH Programming - Introduction HOW-TO: Functions](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [function Man Page - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/function.html)
- [A bash function that takes argument like other languages? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122632/a-bash-function-that-takes-argument-like-other-languages)
- [Passing parameters to a Bash function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212219/passing-parameters-to-a-bash-function)